# Problems exporting animations to Unity 5

Tags: unity, animation, unityscript, skeletal-animation

I've finished a model in SpeedTree Cinema v7.1.1 and the model exports correctly, but I can't figure out how to export the wind animation to Unity 5. The only problem is that the wind animation itself doesn't export.

I think that the problems are one of the following:

1. The way I export the mesh (.FBX ascii).
2. The settings in the export process.

I'll add some images so you understand better.

[image]

(Image 1.) In here you can see the export settings, the important aspects, regarding the animation, are in the 'Extra Data' tab, in there I included Wind, there are other options which I will describe in the next paragraph.

[image]

(Image 2.) In the 'Include' section, in the 'Extra Data' tab I can choose from a variety of things, but I don't know which one will work for exporting the wind animation to Unity 5.

In the 'Extra Data' tab there is also a sections where it says 'Format', under Include, in the 'Format' section the options are FBX/MC, FBX/PC2 and MDD. In the 'Files' sector the options are One or Per Frame.

If you know or think you know how to do this, please tell me, any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you already try some of the formats?

Comment: @derHugo Yes, i already tried all the formats, I tried FBX/MC, FBX/PC2 and MDD (only those formats are available when exporting in fbx). Do you have any idea of what to do ?